# php - How can I find if two timestamps are in the same week?

Tags: php, timestamp

I've got two timestamps. I just want to check if they're in the same week or not. I know I could use

```
if(date('w',$one)==date('w',$two)) {}
```

but the problem is that it is likely to echo different values for 27th of December 2018 and January 1st, 2019. These days can be in the same week but the number of week in year is different and that's why it can't be a reliable solution.
It would be awesome if you provide a solution with the `IntlCalendar` class because my client wants the starting day of week to be Saturday.

Comment: 27th is a Thursday and the 1st is a Tuesday. How are they in the same week?

Comment: I just wanted to give some fake examples on how different days in two years can be in one week

Comment: Same week would do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried and it guess this works. Here is an example (there is a good explanation on https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php btw.):

```
$firstDate = strtotime('2016-12-31');
$secondDate = strtotime('2017-01-01');

//both days are in the same week (number 52 of 2016)
echo date('oW', $firstDate)  . "\n"; //201652
echo date('oW', $secondDate) . "\n"; //201652

//week has to be the same, but also the calendar year, so
echo date('Y', $firstDate)  . "\n"; //2016
echo date('Y', $secondDate) . "\n"; //2017

//if we check both oW AND Y date than we can test wheter 2 days fall within the same week of the same year
$firstDate = strtotime('2016-12-31'); // = Friday of "last" week of 2016
$secondDate = strtotime('2017-01-01'); // = Sunday of "last" week of 2016
$result = date('oW', $firstDate) === date('oW', $secondDate) && date('Y', $firstDate) === date('Y', $secondDate);
var_dump($result); // false (week is the same, but year is different)

$firstDate = strtotime('2017-01-01'); // = Sunday, so still "last" week of 2016
$secondDate = strtotime('2017-01-02'); // = Monday, so first week of 2017
$result = date('oW', $firstDate) === date('oW', $secondDate) && date('Y', $firstDate) === date('Y', $secondDate);
var_dump($result); // false (year is the same, but week is different)

$firstDate = strtotime('2016-12-30');
$secondDate = strtotime('2016-12-31');
$result = date('oW', $firstDate) === date('oW', $secondDate) && date('Y', $firstDate) === date('Y', $secondDate);
var_dump($result); // true (same week, same year)
```

Comment: Amazing. I hadn't noticed on php documentation that for date('o',$s) it says "ISO-8601 week-numbering year. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)". Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could always take one datetime (the one which is more in the past) as a reference, calculate the maximum offset (until the end of the current week) and then compare the dates:

```
<?php

function same_week($s_ref, $s){
    $d_ref = new DateTime($s_ref);
    $d = new DateTime($s);

    $dow = $d_ref->format('w');
    //if the reference is a Saturday, shift one week, otherwise shift
    //until the next Saturday
    $delta = ($dow == 6)?7:(6 - $dow);

    $d_ref->modify("+$delta days midnight");
    return ($d < $d_ref);
}

var_dump(same_week('2018-12-28 12:00:00', '2018-12-29 00:00:00')); //false
var_dump(same_week('2018-12-29 12:00:00', '2019-01-04 10:00:00')); //true
?>
```